# How can i add dynamic values in salt pillars?

Tags: python, salt-stack

Suppose that my pillar value depends on the part of the hostname and based on that string i want to specify pillar values for my jinja template.

```
#/srv/pillar/managefiles.sls 
pkg: 
  heap: 30
```

Comment: SO is not supposed to code for you! Where is your code?

Comment: i dont expect SO to code for me .Where i can i put the code ?  my pillar values iam giving as simple key value pair. I want that value to be generated based on the hostname .where can i embed my python script for the logic inside the pillar sls file ?

Comment: Bellow your question: use the "{}" (code sample) to ad it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont expect SO to code for me .Where i can i put the code ?  my pillar values iam giving as simple key value pair. I want that value to be generated based on the hostname .where can i embed my python script for the logic inside the pillar sls file ? My pillar file in /srv/pillar/managefiles.sls is  pkg: heap:30 . and in my  jinja file iam referring the variable as pillar['pkg']['heap']. Suppose i want to set the heap  based on the hostname ? How can i do that? iam a begineer in salt stack .any replies would be welcomed,

Comment: @Clodion thanks for the quick replies

Comment: i have found the following in salt doc.pkgs:
 { {% if grains['os_family'] == 'RedHat' %}
  apache: httpd
  vim: vim-enhanced
  {% elif grains['os_family'] == 'Debian' %}
  apache: apache2
  vim: vim
  {% elif grains['os'] == 'Arch' %}
  apache: apache
  vim: vim
  {% endif %} } like that how can i get hostname ? can i use socket.hostname in python to get it ?

Comment: Nice! You can add all those precisions, and questions, at your post by editing it! It will be very useful!

Comment: Hi @Clodion are you saying that the information i gave is not sufficient ?

Comment: Don't put details in comments; instead [edit] them to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a scenario with a production systems with big heaps, and a test system with small heaps it could look like this:

```
#/srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  '*prod':
    - managefiles_prod
  '*test':
    - managefiles_test
```

with the pillars

```
#/srv/pillar/managefiles_prod.sls 
pkg: 
  heap: 30
```

and

```
#/srv/pillar/managefiles_test.sls 
pkg: 
  heap: 10
```

The pattern in the `top.sls` file will pick a different pillar file depending on the host name: all host names ending with `prod` will receive production settings, all host names ending with `test` will receive test settings. See the [top file documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html) and [matching with grains](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/grains.html) for more information.